# Setting height of Label as height TableViewCell in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

How can I set height of UILabel as the height of custom TableViewCell contentView?

I use this code and but not get it. I need way to do it with/out storyboard

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    _titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    _titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

After I change bounds of cell, label not redrawn its bounds. How can I set label height as cell height in storyboard?

Comment: instead of using CGRectMake you can assign _titleLabel.frame = self.bounds; The 2 lines below aren't necessary. Are you sure yours _titleLabel is not nil, or its added as contenView subview?

Comment: yes, I am sure, this not helps me. After I change bounds of cell, label not redrawn its bounds . How can I set label height as cell height in storyboard?

Comment: If you are using auto layout, please recheck your auto layout constraints. They might get in the way of this.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `_titleLabel.frame = self.contentView.frame`

Comment: this not helps me. After I change bounds of cell, label not redrawn its bounds. How can I set label height as cell height in storyboard?

Comment: When you change the bounds of your cell, call `-setNeedLayout` on the cell. This will cause `-layoutSubviews` to be called again and fit the label to the new bounds.